# ElasticSearch get data with one value but from multiple places

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have structure something like this:

```
{
   id: "someId",
   age: "15",
   metadata: {
      otherId: "someOtherId"
   }
}
```

and i need to create `query builder` to get all objects where my `dto.providedId == id` or `dto.providedId == metadata.otherId`,

I try do it in this way:

```
if(dto.getProvidedId() != null){
            BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder= new BoolQueryBuilder();
            boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("id.keyword", dto.getProvidedId()));
            boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("metadata.otherId", dto.getProvidedId()));
}
```

but it return me empty array and I don't know why :(

can someone tell me how to do this?

```
{
  "index": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need OR semantics, then you need to use `should` instead of `must``

```
        BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder= new BoolQueryBuilder();
        boolQueryBuilder.minimumShouldMatch(1);
        boolQueryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("id.keyword", dto.getProvidedId()));
        boolQueryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("metadata.otherId", dto.getProvidedId()));
```

Also make sure to check if `metadata.otherId` should not be `metadata.otherId.keyword`.

Comment: nope, not work, also with `.keyword` :/, still empty array

Comment: Can you share your index mapping please?

Comment: i paste in main post

Comment: Thanks but that's not the mappings but the settings. Please run `GET index-name/_mapping` and share the output you get